# Is there a fix for seeing an access 2013 backend on an ubuntu server?

Tags: server, database, microsoft-office

Personally, what I know about Ubuntu can fill a thimble and leave room for your thumb, but the guy that set up my employer's server has a MS thing, even though every other machine in the place uses windows.  My issues is that I was hired to create a database, which I have done, however, in order to make changes on the backend you must open them from the server side.

**Is there a method by which I can reach those Access 2013 .accdb files?**

Comment: See if this looks interesting to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420653/odbc-connection-to-ms-access-on-ubuntu